# Laravel 4 authentication fails with new accounts

Tags: authentication, hash, laravel-4

I have a problem with logging in new users that I have created. My login form works expectedly for all accounts that have been created before today. However, any new accounts created under (apparently) the same model do not work.

I have print_r()'ed the user authentication details, and the username and password is as expected. Could it be that something has happened with hashing? I suspect that all accounts would fail to log in if that was the case? Could anyone suggest how I can debug this problem?

Comment: Since passwords are hashed, how do you know for sure the password is as expected?

Comment: well i think it is! i've tried to hash the input to see if it's the same as the password. i suspect it isn't. so i'm redoing the whole User model/authentication bit. thanks for the comment.